# How to handle example data in R Package that has UTF-8 marked strings

Tags: r, twitter, utf-8

I would like to include an example dataset (of `Twitter` tweets and `metadata`) in an `R` Package I'm writing.

I downloaded an example data.frame using the `Twitter API` and saved it as `.RData` (with the corresponding .`R` data description file) in my package.

When I run `R CMD` Check, I get the following NOTE,

```
 * checking data for non-ASCII characters ... NOTE
 Note: found 287 marked UTF-8 strings
```

I tried saving the `data.frame` with `ASCII=TRUE`, hoping this would fix the problem. But it persists. Any idea on how I can get `R CMD` CHECK to run without notes?

(also, I would be open to removing all `UTF-8` marked strings from the example data if that's the solution). Thank you!

example row from data.frame:

```
First time in SF (@ San Francisco International Airport (SFO) - @flysfo in San Francisco, CA) https://t.co/1245xqxtwesr
  favorited favoriteCount replyToSN             created truncated replyToSID                 id replyToUID
1     FALSE             0      <NA> 2015-03-13 23:30:35     FALSE       <NA> 576525795927179264       <NA>
                                                   statusSource screenName retweetCount isRetweet retweeted
1 <a href="http://foursquare.com" rel="nofollow">Foursquare</a>  my_name93            0     FALSE     FALSE
      longitude    latitude
1 -122.38100052 37.61865062
```

Comment: It looks like you need to paste `"/@href"` to your xpath query, or `XML::xmlGetAttr(a, "href")` on the node `a`.  Using `as(statusSource, "character")` may also work.  But can we see the code of call you made to get the original data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case it's useful to anyone in the future, the resolution I found is this:

The UTF-8 marked characters were in the dataset because Twitter tweets sometimes include emoji's.

The advice I was given is that there isn't a straightforward way to get rid of the NOTE in the PACKAGE CMD CHECK without just removing all of the UTF-8 marked strings.

To do this, I used the command:

`nonUTF <- iconv(df$TroubleVector, from="UTF-8", to="ASCII")`

on the vector that had emoji's, etc. This command returned NA if the value had UTF-8 marked strings. I used this to subset the dataset - now I get a clean build.

Answer (score 0):

I did a google search for a [UTF-8 to ASCII online converter](https://www.google.com/search?q=utf8+to+ascii+online+converter), pasted in my code, converted it, and pasted it back into my script.

Since this answer was downvoted, it drew my attention to the original site I linked to being non-performant. So I removed that specific link from the answer. If you stumble upon a bad one, use another on as there are many available in the top results in google.

Answer (score 0):

The `stringi::stri_enc_toascii()` in `stringi` package solves my problem in my package developement.

```r
> stringi::stri_enc_isascii(a)
  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [18] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [35] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [52] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [69] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [86] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[103] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[120] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[137] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[154] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> b <- stringi::stri_enc_toascii(a)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> stringi::stri_enc_isascii(b)
  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [22] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [43] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [64] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [85] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[106] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[127] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[148] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```