# About the use of Encoding function

Tags: r, encoding

I am using the following code for importing special characters in R:

```
Encoding(self$Data$Skills) <- "UTF-8"
```

But when I change the name of the column with:

```
colnames(self$Data) <- 'skills2'
```

and run again:

```
Encoding(self$Data$skills2) <- "UTF-8"
```

I have the following error:

```
Error in `Encoding<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "UTF-8") : 
a character vector argument expected
```

I do not understand why is this happening. Any idea? Additionally, the same is happening if I want to sample data from this dataframe. Using:

```
self$Data <- data.frame(df[sample(nrow(self$Data),dim(self$Data)[1]*samplePersentance),])
```

the column name changes and when i encoding function i got the same error.The data is imported using `read.csv` function.

**Edit**:
Head of the data

```
                         Skills
1                          null
2                           "'"
3                  "'Fin Gaap'"
4 "'Knæ-igennem-hinanden-tr..."
5 "'Mønt-dans-på-knoerne-tr..."
6  "'Necessary knowledge of..."

> typeof(self$Data)
[1] "list"

> class(self$Data)
[1] "data.frame"
```

And to reproduce the error:

```
try1 <- structure(list(Skills = c("null", "\"'\"", "\"'Fin Gaap'\"", 
"\"'KnÃ¦-igennem-hinanden-tr...\"", "\"'MÃ¸nt-dans-pÃ¥-knoerne-tr...\"", 
"\"'Necessary knowledge of...\"")), .Names = "Skills", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")


Encoding(try1$Skills) <- 'UTF-8'
#the function runs normally
try2 <- data.frame(try1[sample(nrow(try1),floor(dim(try1)[1]*0.5)),])
colnames(try2) <- 'skills2'
Encoding(try2$skills2) <- 'UTF-8'
#the function output an error.

> typeof(try1$skills)
'character'
> typeof(try2$skills)
'intiger'
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: There is a typo in `colnames(seld$Data) <- 'column2'`. It should be 'sel**f**'.

Comment: Nice that you correct it here, but I assume it's also in your code and the reason for the error.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the typo. It is just here, not in the code.

Comment: `head` only is useless, please post the output of `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: Again a typo: It's `Skills` in your data, but you use `skills` for subsetting. If I correct that, there is no error.

Comment: Your "reproducible" example is not reproducible at all. I get the error at the first `Encoding` and not at the second. And the first error is just due to a capital letter as pointed out by @Roland. Be more careful in treating data.

Comment: You are right. But I sould have given the specific example. The problem begins when i sample the data.

Comment: So finally the problem was that I had to add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in data.frame when I was sampling. Sorry for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `data.frame` with its default `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` turns the column into a factor:

```
try2 <- data.frame(try1[sample(nrow(try1),floor(dim(try1)[1]*0.5)),])
colnames(try2) <- 'skills2'
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ skills2: Factor w/ 3 levels "\"'\"","\"'Fin Gaap'\"",..: 3 1 2

str(try2)
Encoding(try2$skills2) <- 'UTF-8'
#Error in `Encoding<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "UTF-8") : 
#  a character vector argument expected

try2$skills2 <-as.character(try2$skills2)
Encoding(try2$skills2) <- 'UTF-8'
#works
```

Of course you don't need `data.frame` in that line at all ...

Comment: Yea, exactly. I used the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when I was creating the data.frame at the sampling.