# Error extracting noun in R using KoNLP

Tags: r, csv, encoding, nlp, extract

I tried to extract noun for R. When using program R, an error appears. I wrote the following code:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\kyu\\Desktop\\1-1file")
library(KoNLP)
useSejongDic()

txt <- readLines(file("1_2000.csv"))
nouns <- sapply(txt, extractNoun, USE.NAMES = F)
```

and, the error appear like this:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\kyu\\Desktop\\1-1file")
library(KoNLP)
useSejongDic() 

Backup was just finished!
87007 words were added to dic_user.txt. 

txt <- readLines(file("1_2000.csv"))
nouns <- sapply(txt, extractNoun, USE.NAMES = F)
```

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error in
>   `Encoding<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "UTF-8") :    a character vector
>   argument expected

Why is this happening? I load [1_2000.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw40xYYVtv3nY0owOW5DMDNrZmM/view?usp=sharing%22) file, there are 2000 lines of data. Is this too much data? How do I extract noun like large data file? I use R 3.2.4 with RStudio, and Excel version 2016 on Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: please post the result of `dput(txt)` to make the error reproducible

Comment: you mean that post 1_2000.csv file?

Comment: sure, why not? i want to share that file but i don't know how to share that file i sign up yesterday, so i can't use well that interface stackoverflow web page could you mind help me to post that file? and, that file is made up korean language it is ok?

Comment: you can host the file externally (e.g. on Google Drive or Dropbox) and share the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of lines shouldn't be a problem.

I think that there might be a problem with the encoding. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731891/about-the-use-of-encoding-function). Your .csv file is encoded as EUC-KR.

I changed the encoding to UTF-8 using

```
txtUTF <- read.csv(file.choose(), encoding = 'UTF-8')
nouns <- sapply(txtUTF, extractNoun, USE.NAMES = F)
```

But that results in the following error:

> Warning message:
>   In preprocessing(sentence) : Input must be legitimate character!

So this might be an error with your input. I can't read Korean so can't help you further.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. really really thank you. when i use that code, error appear "In preprocessing(sentence) : Input must be legitimate character!" this. i ignore that, keep going other code, when i see boken character. although i can't solve this problem, you tried enough. i really appreciate. thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You might want to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it worked for you.